# Environment variables in application.yml doesn't work with default values that start with a space

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have following **application.yml**:

```
sftp:
  sessionFactory:
    host: ${HOST:127.0.0.1}
    username: ${USERNAME:test}
    password: ${PASSWORD: test}
```

The password **starts with a space**. When starting the Spring Boot application it is crashing with:

```
    Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 26, column 25:
        password: ${PASSWORD: test}
```

When trying with *${PASSWORD:' test'}*, the value of the password is *password=' test'* instead of *password= test*.

Before introducing the environment variables the **application.yml** looked like this:

```
sftp:
  sessionFactory:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    username: test
    password: ' test'
```

and everything worked properly.

Any idea how such a default value that starts with space can be specified?
Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Edit:
I want to clarify that SpEL only works for `@Value` bound properties as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation). `@ConfigurationProperties` does not support SpEL expressions.

[SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef) lets you combine raw strings and operaters. In your case you just want a plain string so you can define your property like so:

```
password: ${PASSWORD:#{' test'}}
```

##Example code

application.yaml

```
testing:
  my:
    username: ${USERNAME:user}
    password: ${PASSWORD:#{' test'}}
```

Testing.java

```
@Component
public class Testing {

  @Value("${testing.my.username}")
  String username;

  @Value("${testing.my.password}")
  String password;

  @PostConstruct
  public void post() {
    System.out.println("User: (" + username + ")");
    System.out.println("Pass: (" + password + ")");
  }
```

log

```
User: (user)
Pass: ( test)
```

Comment: It is not working...the expression is not evaluated...the value of the password is *password=#{' test'}*...thanks anyway

Comment: It worked for me. I'll update the response with my example code.

Comment: it doesn't work for me too, when using @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "testing.my")